# Channel shutdown: channel error

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

sometimes i found follow entry in my log file. I have no idea what the problem is. My guess is to set a lower request heartbeat. Any other ideas?
Additionally i had the situtation that after a rabbit restart my server was not able to reestablish the service after the rabbit was back. I have to restart my server, that a reconnection is possible.

```
[AMQP Connection xxx:5672] [ERROR] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'xxxx' in vhost 'aaa', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

The exchange and queue are not auto-delete?

public class AmqpConfiguration {

```
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;  

@Bean
public Queue receiverQueue() {
    return new Queue("receiverQueue", true, false, false, getDeadLetterExchangeArgs());
}

@Bean
public FanoutExchange senderExchange() {
    return new FanoutExchange("xxxx");
}

@Bean
public Queue deadLetterQueue() {
    return new Queue("deadLetterQueue");
}

@Bean
public FanoutExchange exchangeDeadLetter() {
    return new FanoutExchange("deadLetter.exchange");
}


@Bean
public Binding bindDeadLetterQueueToExchange() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(deadLetterQueue()).to(exchangeDeadLetter());
}


@Bean
public Binding bindSenderExchangeToQueue() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(receiverQueue()).to(senderExchange());
}

@Bean(name = { "listenerContainerFactory" })
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory() {
    final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    containerFactory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
    containerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    // TODO: set heartbeat

    return containerFactory;
}

private Map<String, Object> getDeadLetterExchangeArgs() {
    final Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", amqpProperties.getDeadLetterExchange());
    return args;
}
```

}

Cheers,

Dennis

Comment: You need to show your configuration - is the exchange auto-delete? If so, what are you using to declare the exchange on the broker?

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, see comments in orginal post

Answer (score 0):

> no exchange 'xxxx' in vhost 'aaa'

I don't see an exchange `xxxx` in the configuration you showed.

Perhaps you have some bogus code sending to that exchange?

**EDIT**

If it's a boot app, and you are using the amqp starter, the rabbit autoconfiguration will create an admin for you. After restarting the server, you should see messages like these (if you enable DEBUG logging)...

```
09:43:03.450 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] INFO  o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Created new connection: SimpleConnection@b6e2e2c [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/]
09:43:03.451 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin - Initializing declarations
09:43:03.451 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'senderExchange'
09:43:03.451 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'receiverQueue'
09:43:03.451 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'bindSenderExchangeToQueue'
09:43:03.451 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry'
09:43:03.452 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
09:43:03.452 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - Executing callback on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
09:43:03.452 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin - declaring Exchange 'xxxx'
09:43:03.452 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin - declaring Queue 'receiverQueue'
09:43:03.453 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin - Binding destination [receiverQueue (QUEUE)] to exchange [xxxx] with routing key []
09:43:03.453 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin - Declarations finished
```

The admin is registered as a listener to the connection factory and always declares the queues/exchanges/bindings when the connection is established.

Do you have multiple connection factories/vhosts? If so, you need an admin for each - see the [section on conditional declaration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#conditional-declaration).

Comment: I think the exchange is the FanoutExchange in the orginal error code is the xxxxx a ip adress. no exchange 'xxx.xx.x.xxx'. I extended the confguration.

Comment: How are declaring these entities (exchanges etc)? I don't see a `RabbitAdmin` in your configuration, which would automatically declare them when the connection is created. If you are declaring them yourself, perhaps you have a race condition.

Comment: It's a spring boot application like https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/. The queue() method creates an AMQP queue. The exchange() method creates a fanout exchange. The binding() method binds these two together, defining the behavior that occurs when RabbitTemplate publishes to an exchange. So for what do i need a RabbitAdmin?
The configuration works till the rabbit mq is restartet, then the queues cannot reconnect. Maybe that is a rabbit-mq cluster problem and the queues will move to antoher node after.

Comment: Exchanges exist on all nodes so that can't be the problem; do you have multiple vhosts? See my edit for information about the RabbitAdmin.

Comment: Sorry Gary for the late reply.

Comment: Sorry Gary for the late reply. The RabbitMQ was down. The queue will stop the reconnection after 3 times, if the reconnection failed. I set containerFactory.setMissingQueuesFatal( false ) to solve the problem.